# Is "Neither I you" Correct?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, phrases, expressions, expression-choice

A friend of mine said "...I never saw you during school."

For some reason I wanted to respond "Neither I you." I am certain I have heard this reply before, but, looking at it now, it does not seem grammatically correct.

Is saying "Neither I you" correct? If not what would be the most concise to tell him that I had not seen him either ie Neither have I seen you?

Comment: That should really be “Nor I you.”

Comment: You would say "nor I you" as already mentioned or "nor did I you" or "nor did I see you", but his sentence is not great. "I did not see you during school" (today) or "I have never seen you during school" (ever) are less ambiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find it comprehensible. I would not write it, but I could imagine myself saying it. I consider it an elliptical reduction like so:

> Neither [did] I [see] you.

In one of the other answers we have:

> Nor did I see you.

I probably wouldn't use that construction very frequently, but I don't think it is wrong.

Probably the clearest way to say what you want would be to write the sentence as follows:

> I didn't see you either

Thus, you avoid some difficulties incumbent in the use of neither and nor (which are perhaps differences between BrE and AmE?)

Answer (score 6):

I'd consider "Nor I you" acceptable, as an elliptical form of "Nor did I see you."

Answer (score 1):

The answer "Neither I you" would, to my mind, pass muster as a short verbal response, that might be somewhat 'terse' - say for example I was a bit put out that I hadn't met up with the speaker. 
It also has a slight feel of the Victorian era about it, and might well have been uttered by perhaps Holmes when he was exasperated by Watson, for example. 
Or indeed in a written form such as a "cable" when every word cost ~ which makes one wonder: Might it be found somewhere in Twitter these days ?

Answer (score 0):

In all use of "Neither" with "I/you etc." we face an elliptical spoken form where the verb is mute but fully understood which is the main aim.

So *"Neither I you"* means "Neither (did) I (see) you". But back in UK you must prevent such expression :)