# "Nor did I" or "Neither did I"

Tags: negation, auxiliary-verbs, neither-nor

These two questions are from a mobile app:

> 1. I didn't pass my driving test.
>      *correct answer:* "Nor did I."
> 2. He didn't pass his driving test.
>      *correct answer:* "Neither did I."

Why do we use *nor* in the first sentence and *neither* in the second? Is there any exact rule to follow?

[image: http://s29.postimg.org/lus33n3tz/11018083_10204090882574863_8430856177979965846_n.jpg]

[image: http://s23.postimg.org/93olrbwl7/1424531_10204091120900821_5373380401800323557_n.jpg]

Comment: What is the name of the app? The answers seems entirely arbitrary; I would reply with *Neither* in both cases, but I wouldn't consider *Nor* incorrect in either case.

Comment: Here is the app web link http://englishteststore.net/

Comment: It doesn't seem like an particularly good English test.

Comment: FWIW, I disagree with the answers to the very first questions on the sample basic error recognition tests 002, 003, and 007 (in that there are other uses I would deem incorrect, like missing articles), so I don't know how much faith I would put into this app.

Comment: I know, some apps aren't trustworthy enough to count on them.  I have a group on face book and I really got mad at this app when a member posted this question. I'm still waiting for a clear cut answer.

Comment: This app gives a justification for the answer and it goes like this: 1)To agree with a negative statement: nor\ neither+ auxiliary verb\ modal+ pronoun.
2) Change the auxiliary verb related to the original statement.
Apparently, it concentrates on the subject-verb inversion, but I don't know why "Neither" in the first question is unlikely " according to the app" while the inversion took place.

Comment: Both answers are correct. But the app was wrong in marking "neither did I" as incorrect.

Comment: In order not to forget.. Special thanks for choster :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A: John **doesn't smoke**
>   B: Neither do I
>   C: Nor do I
>   D: I don't either
>   E: Me neither

They're all correct, E is "nonstandard English", I wouldn't recommend writing it in a formal paper or in an exam, but it's fine in conversation.

> A: John **didn't pass** the test
>   B: Neither did I
>   C: Nor did I
>   D: I didn't either
>   E: Me neither

All these answers are perfectly acceptable. We use **neither** and **nor** + **auxiliary/modal verb** + **subject** to mean ‘also not’:

> A: John does nothing all day, he hardly works
>   B: Neither does Alice
>   C: Nor does Alice

We can use **subject** + **auxiliary** + **not** + **either** to mean ‘also not’,

> D: Alice doesn't either

But  the expressions ***me too*** and  ***me neither***  are only used in very informal speech, and can only be used with first person singular. So ...

> E: *Her neither

In this case E is ungrammatical.

**To sum up:** The app was wrong in marking *neither did I* as being incorrect. Both *Nor did I* and *Neither did I* are acceptable short answers.

Sources: [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/neither-neither-nor-and-not-either) and [BBC learning English](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv166.shtml)
See also this question [Is “Neither I you” Correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145197/is-neither-i-you-correct/145201#145201)

Here's another source: (Collins COBUILD Active English Grammar. HarperCollins, 2003)

> "You use 'so,' 'neither,' or 'nor' with an auiliary, modal, or the main verb 'be.' The verb comes before the subject.
>
> > > You were different then. -- So **were** you.
> > >       I don't normally drink at lunch. -- Neither **do** I.
> > >       I can't do it. -- Nor **can** I.
>
> You can use 'not either' instead of 'neither,' in which case the verb comes after the subject.
>
> > He doesn't understand. -- **We don't** either

Comment: Thank you Mari-Lou A for your answer and for your big effort just to give a hand.

Answer (score 3):

I'm gonna have to disagree with the app.

`Neither` is the negative of `either`.

Both the questions can be answered:

> I didn't pass it either.

Which can be phrased as `Neither did I`

`Nor` is the negative of `or`.

I don't think `Nor did I` would not be appropriate in either situation, (even though it sounds acceptable because, like neither, it is widely used to introduce a further negative statement).

For `nor` to be applicable, there should be a corresponding phrasing using `or`.

`Or I didn't pass it` doesn't sound like something anyone would reply

`Nor` would be appropriate in sentences where a negation of `or` is needed, like.

> I didn't pass my cooking test, **nor did I** pass my driving test.

Alternatively, I didn't pass my cooking test or my driving test.

Comment: @NizarAl-Arqan: Dude, you can only accept one answer. Not all of them! Pick the one that helped you the most.

Comment: Lol. what if I accept them all? :) a good question to be answered >>

Comment: @NizarAl-Arqan: The asker gets to accept one answer that works from them best. The accepted answer earns 15 points and the asker gets 2 points for accepting. The accepted answer is shown as the first answer. After that it's shown in decreasing order of votes. Everyone can vote, but only the asker can accept. For more info, read the tour page.

Comment: @NizarAl-Arqan: And the asker can change the answer they accepted if they want.

Answer (score 0):

OK, people, let us see how people talk, not apps. Right, people? :-)

So, let's take the bright path leading to Google Books and search there for:

> ---

**THE [UNOFFICIAL] WINNER**

["he did not and **neither** **did** I"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%20%22He%20did%20not.%20Nor%20did%20I%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22he%20did%20not%20and%20neither%20did%20I%22)
About 101 results

> ---

["he did not and **nor** **did** I"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%20%22He%20did%20not.%20Nor%20did%20I%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22he%20did%20not%20and%20nor%20did%20I%22)
2 results

["he did not and I **didn't either**"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%20%22He%20did%20not.%20Nor%20did%20I%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22he%20did%20not%20and%20I%20didn%27t%20either%22)
2 results

> _

Now, after delighting us with stats, let's mention examples for the least fortunate two cases, just to show you they don't look that bad, **one of them coming from the British Parliament!**.

So, they are not exactly chaff :-)

E.g.

> White Heat Cold Logic: British Computer Art 1960-1980 - Page 148 Paul
>   Brown - 2008
>
> No, **he did not, and nor did I;** it was another couple of years
>   before I spotted the key that unlocked the door to AARON's development
>   as a colorist. The breakthrough on color came for me in 1985, and it
>   followed from the realization, so obvious .

E.g.

> Parliamentary Papers: 1850-1908 - Volume 31 - Page 286 Great Britain.
>   Parliament. House of Commons - 1894
>
> Just tell us the facts, please, as shortly as you can 'l—-I waited for
>   him to breach the subject, but **he did not, and I didn't either**,
>   and I went away without having spoken on the subject at all or having
>   met Madame O'Grady.

Comment: Marius Hancu,
your efforts are well appreciated. It's a beneficial web site. I really like it and like the way it works and appreciate all those who are working to let things go the righteous way.